# How to implement a Least Frequently Used (LFU) cache?

Tags: java, algorithm, caching

Least Frequently Used (LFU) is a type of cache algorithm used to manage memory within a computer. The standard characteristics of this method involve the system keeping track of the number of times a block is referenced in memory. When the cache is full and requires more room the system will purge the item with the lowest reference frequency.

What would be the best way to implement a most-recently-used cache of objects, say in Java?

I've already implemented one using LinkedHashMap(by maintaining the no. of times objects are accessed) But I'm curious if any of the new concurrent collections would be better candidates.

Consider this case : Suppose cache is full and we need to make space for another one. Say two objects are noted in cache which are accessed for one time only.  Which one to remove if we come to know that other(which is not in cache)object is being accessed for more than once ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use an existing implementation, such as that from Guava.

Comment: Keep a counter for each cache entry, and increment the appropriate counter on each successful reference.  If a counter overflows, divide ALL counters by 2 (or 4 or whatever) to "rescale" them.  The entry with the lowest count is the least frequently used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. According to me, the best way to implement a most-recently-used cache of objects would be to include a new variable as 'latestTS' for each object. TS stands for timestamp.

   // A static method that returns the current date and time as milliseconds since January 1st 1970
   long latestTS = System.currentTimeMillis();
2. ConcurrentLinkedHashMap is not yet implemented in Concurrent Java Collections. 
   (Ref: [Java Concurrent Collection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)). However, you can try and use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) and [DoublyLinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
3. About the case to be considered: in such case, as I have said that you can declare latestTS variable, based upon the value of latestTS variable, you can remove an entry and add the new object. (Don't forget to update frequency and latestTS of the new object added)

As you have mentioned, you can use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) as it gives element access in O(1) and also, you get the order traversal.
Please, find the below code for LFU Cache:
(PS: The below code is the answer for the question in the title i.e. "How to implement LFU cache")

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LFUCache {

    class CacheEntry
    {
        private String data;
        private int frequency;

        // default constructor
        private CacheEntry()
        {}

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }
        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public int getFrequency() {
            return frequency;
        }
        public void setFrequency(int frequency) {
            this.frequency = frequency;
        }       

    }

    private static int initialCapacity = 10;

    private static LinkedHashMap<Integer, CacheEntry> cacheMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, CacheEntry>();
    /* LinkedHashMap is used because it has features of both HashMap and LinkedList. 
     * Thus, we can get an entry in O(1) and also, we can iterate over it easily.
     * */

    public LFUCache(int initialCapacity)
    {
        this.initialCapacity = initialCapacity;
    }

    public void addCacheEntry(int key, String data)
    {
        if(!isFull())
        {
            CacheEntry temp = new CacheEntry();
            temp.setData(data);
            temp.setFrequency(0);

            cacheMap.put(key, temp);
        }
        else
        {
            int entryKeyToBeRemoved = getLFUKey();
            cacheMap.remove(entryKeyToBeRemoved);

            CacheEntry temp = new CacheEntry();
            temp.setData(data);
            temp.setFrequency(0);

            cacheMap.put(key, temp);
        }
    }

    public int getLFUKey()
    {
        int key = 0;
        int minFreq = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, CacheEntry> entry : cacheMap.entrySet())
        {
            if(minFreq > entry.getValue().frequency)
            {
                key = entry.getKey();
                minFreq = entry.getValue().frequency;
            }           
        }

        return key;
    }

    public String getCacheEntry(int key)
    {
        if(cacheMap.containsKey(key))  // cache hit
        {
            CacheEntry temp = cacheMap.get(key);
            temp.frequency++;
            cacheMap.put(key, temp);
            return temp.data;
        }
        return null; // cache miss
    }

    public static boolean isFull()
    {
        if(cacheMap.size() == initialCapacity)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the key while adding in the map is the same key but it's value is different so we might need to just increase the frequency of the key and set its value to be different.

Comment: Evictions will run in O(n) time with this algorithm, but O(log(n)) should be possible if a heap is used.

Comment: Once the cache is full, each new addition is going to do a linear search of the map looking for the best entry to delete. Horrible. In my implementation, I'm allowing the map to grow to twice its target size, then doing a rebuild that drops half the entries: the cost of the rebuild is higher, but its frequency is much lower.

Answer (score 13):

You might benefit from the LFU implementation of ActiveMQ: [**LFUCache**](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-kahadb-store/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/util/LFUCache.java)

They have provided some good functionality.

Answer (score 6):

I think, the LFU data structure must combine priority queue (for maintaining fast access to lfu item) and hash map (for providing fast access to any item by its key); I would suggest the following node definition for each object stored in cache:

```
class Node<T> {
   // access key
   private int key;
   // counter of accesses
   private int numAccesses;
   // current position in pq
   private int currentPos;
   // item itself
   private T item;
   //getters, setters, constructors go here
}
```

You need `key` for referring to an item.
You need `numAccesses` as a key for priority queue.
You need `currentPos` to be able to quickly find a pq position of item by key.
Now  you organize hash map (key(`Integer`) -> node(`Node<T>`)) to quickly access items and min heap-based priority queue using number of accesses as priority. Now you can very quickly perform all operations (access, add new item, update number of acceses, remove lfu). You need to write each operation carefully, so that it maintains all the nodes consistent (their number of accesses, their position in pq and there existence in hash map). All operations will work with constant average time complexity which is what you expect from cache.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the o(1) implementation for LFU - http://dhruvbird.com/lfu.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: A link to a PDF is not helpful unless you're Google. If you've read the paper yourself, please summarize it.

Comment: I read the link and  Author/s suggesting to Use 
1) HashMap
2) LinkedList for storing/connecting items  sorted frequency
3) LinkedList for storing elements of the same frequency

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to implement this below LFU cache implementation. Took reference from this -
[LFU](http://dhruvbird.com/lfu.pdf) paper. My implementation is working nicely.

If anyone wants to provide any further suggestion to improve it again, please let me know.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class LFUCacheImplementation {

    private Map<Integer, Node> cache = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    private TreeMap<Integer, DoublyLinkedList> frequencies = new TreeMap<>();
    private final int CAPACITY;

    public LFUCache(int capacity) {
        this.CAPACITY = capacity;
    }

    public int get(int key) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(key)) {
            return -1;
        }

        Node node = cache.get(key);

        int frequency = counts.get(key);
        frequencies.get(frequency).remove(new Node(node.key(), node.value()));
        removeFreq(frequency);
        frequencies.computeIfAbsent(frequency + 1, k -> new DoublyLinkedList()).add(new Node(node.key(), node.value()));

        counts.put(key, frequency + 1);
        return cache.get(key).value();
    }

    public void set(int key, int value) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(key)) {

            Node node = new Node(key, value);

            if (cache.size() == CAPACITY) {

                int l_count = frequencies.firstKey();
                Node deleteThisNode = frequencies.get(l_count).head();
                frequencies.get(l_count).remove(deleteThisNode);

                int deleteThisKey = deleteThisNode.key();
                removeFreq(l_count);
                cache.remove(deleteThisKey);
                counts.remove(deleteThisKey);
            }

            cache.put(key, node);
            counts.put(key, 1);
            frequencies.computeIfAbsent(1, k -> new DoublyLinkedList()).add(node);
        }
    }

    private void removeFreq(int frequency) {
        if (frequencies.get(frequency).size() == 0) {
            frequencies.remove(frequency);
        }
    }

    public Map<Integer, Node> getCache() {
        return cache;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> getCounts() {
        return counts;
    }

    public TreeMap<Integer, DoublyLinkedList> getFrequencies() {
        return frequencies;
    }
}

class Node {
    private int key;
    private int value;
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;

    public Node(int key, int value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    public void setPrev(Node prev) {
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    public int key() {
        return key;
    }

    public int value() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Node)) return false;
        Node node = (Node) o;
        return key == node.key &&
                value == node.value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node{" +
                "key=" + key +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}

class DoublyLinkedList {
    private int size;
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    public void add(Node node) {
        if (null == head) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            tail.setNext(node);
            node.setPrev(tail);
        }
        tail = node;
        size++;
    }

    public void remove(Node node) {
        if(null == head || null == node) {
            return;
        }
        if(this.size() == 1 && head.equals(node)) {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        } else if (head.equals(node)) {
            head = node.getNext();
            head.setPrev(null);
        } else if (tail.equals(node)) {
            Node prevToTail = tail.getPrev();
            prevToTail.setNext(null);
            tail = prevToTail;
        } else {
            Node current = head.getNext();

            while(!current.equals(tail)) {
                if(current.equals(node)) {
                    Node prevToCurrent = current.getPrev();
                    Node nextToCurrent = current.getNext();
                    prevToCurrent.setNext(nextToCurrent);
                    nextToCurrent.setPrev(prevToCurrent);
                    break;
                }
               current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
        size--;
    }

    public Node head() {
        return head;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Client code to use the above cache implementation -

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        LFUCache cache = new LFUCache(4);
        cache.set(11, function(11));
        cache.set(12, function(12));
        cache.set(13, function(13));
        cache.set(14, function(14));
        cache.set(15, function(15));
        client.print(cache.getFrequencies());

        cache.get(13);
        cache.get(13);
        cache.get(13);
        cache.get(14);
        cache.get(14);
        cache.get(14);
        cache.get(14);
        client.print(cache.getCache());
        client.print(cache.getCounts());
        client.print(cache.getFrequencies());
    }

    public void print(Map<Integer, ? extends Object> map) {

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, ? extends Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue() instanceof Node) {
                System.out.println("Cache Key => "+entry.getKey()+", Cache Value => "+((Node) entry.getValue()).toString());
            } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof DoublyLinkedList) {
                System.out.println("Frequency Key => "+entry.getKey()+" Frequency Values => [");
                Node head = ((DoublyLinkedList) entry.getValue()).head();
                while(null != head) {
                    System.out.println(head.toString());
                    head = head.getNext();
                }
                System.out.println(" ]");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Count Key => "+entry.getKey()+", Count Value => "+entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    public static int function(int key) {
        int prime = 31;
        return key*prime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a priority queue? You can keep elements sorted there with keys representing the frequency. Just update the object position in the queue after visiting it. You can update just from time to time for optimizing the performance (but reducing precision).

Comment: How you compute the key values?

Comment: I would use a global counter `C`, counting all usages. Then for each object `o` I would remember the value of `C` when it was created `start(o)` and the number of uses `uses(o)` of that element. Finally, the frequency of this object is given by `uses(o) / (C - start(o))`. Of course one needs to work out details but I hope that this explains the idea.

Comment: a queue allows access to its head only so this cant be used for a caching

Answer (score 0):

Many implementations I have seen have runtime complexity `O(log(n))`. This means, when the cache size is `n`, the time needed to insert/remove an element into/from chache is logarithmic. Such implementations use usually a `min heap` to maintain usage frequencies of elements. The root of the heap contains the element with lowest frequency, and can be accessed in `O(1)` time. But to maintain the heap property we have to move an element, every time it is used (and frequency is incremented) inside of the heap, to place it into proper position, or when we have to insert new element into the cache (and so put it into the heap).
But the runtime complexity can be reduced to `O(1)`, when we maintain a `hashmap` (Java) or `unordered_map` (C++) with the element as key. Additinally we need two sorts of lists, `frequency list` and `elements lists`. The `elements lists` contain elements that have same frequency, and the `frequency list` contain the `element lists`.

```
  frequency list
  1   3   6   7
  a   k   y   x
  c   l       z
  m   n
```

Here in the example we see the `frequency list` that has 4 elements (4 `elements lists`). The element list `1` contains elements `(a,c,m)`, the elements list `3` contains elements `(k, l, n)` etc.
Now, when we use say element `y`, we have to increment its frequency and put it in the next list. Because the elements list with frequency 6 becomes empty, we delete it. The result is:

```
  frequency list
  1   3   7
  a   k   y
  c   l   x
  m   n   z
```

We place the element y in the begin of the `elements list` 7. When we have to remove elements from the list later, we will start from the end (first `z`, then `x` and then `y`).
Now, when we use element `n`, we have to increment its frequency and put it into the new list, with frequencies 4:

```
  frequency list
  1   3   4  7
  a   k   n  y
  c   l      x
  m          z
```

I hope the idea is clear. I provide now my C++ implementation of the LFU cache, and will add later a Java implementation.
The class has just 2 public methods, `void set(key k, value v)`
and `bool get(key k, value &v)`. In the get method the value to retrieve will be set per reference when the element is found, in this case the method returns true. When the element is not found, the method returns false.

```
#include<unordered_map>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned uint;

template<typename K, typename V = K>
struct Entry
{
    K key;
    V value;
};


template<typename K, typename V = K>
class LFUCache
{

typedef  typename list<typename Entry<K, V>> ElementList;
typedef typename list <pair <uint, ElementList>> FrequencyList;

private:
    unordered_map <K, pair<typename FrequencyList::iterator, typename ElementList::iterator>> cacheMap;
    FrequencyList elements;
    uint maxSize;
    uint curSize;

    void incrementFrequency(pair<typename FrequencyList::iterator, typename ElementList::iterator> p) {
        if (p.first == prev(elements.end())) {
            //frequency list contains single list with some frequency, create new list with incremented frequency (p.first->first + 1)
            elements.push_back({ p.first->first + 1, { {p.second->key, p.second->value} } });
            // erase and insert the key with new iterator pair
            cacheMap[p.second->key] = { prev(elements.end()), prev(elements.end())->second.begin() };
        }
        else {
            // there exist element(s) with higher frequency
            auto pos = next(p.first);
            if (p.first->first + 1 == pos->first)
                // same frequency in the next list, add the element in the begin
                pos->second.push_front({ p.second->key, p.second->value });
            else
                // insert new list before next list
                pos = elements.insert(pos, { p.first->first + 1 , {{p.second->key, p.second->value}} });
            // update cachMap iterators
            cacheMap[p.second->key] = { pos, pos->second.begin() };
        }
        // if element list with old frequency contained this singe element, erase the list from frequency list
        if (p.first->second.size() == 1)
            elements.erase(p.first);
        else
            // erase only the element with updated frequency from the old list
            p.first->second.erase(p.second);
    }

    void eraseOldElement() {
        if (elements.size() > 0) {
            auto key = prev(elements.begin()->second.end())->key;
            if (elements.begin()->second.size() < 2)
                elements.erase(elements.begin());
            else
                elements.begin()->second.erase(prev(elements.begin()->second.end()));
            cacheMap.erase(key);
            curSize--;
        }
    }

public:
    LFUCache(uint size) {
        if (size > 0)
            maxSize = size;
        else
            maxSize = 10;
        curSize = 0;
    }
    void set(K key, V value) {
        auto entry = cacheMap.find(key);
        if (entry == cacheMap.end()) {
            if (curSize == maxSize)
                eraseOldElement();
            if (elements.begin() == elements.end()) {
                elements.push_front({ 1, { {key, value} } });
            }
            else if (elements.begin()->first == 1) {
                elements.begin()->second.push_front({ key,value });
            }
            else {
                elements.push_front({ 1, { {key, value} } });
            }
            cacheMap.insert({ key, {elements.begin(), elements.begin()->second.begin()} });
            curSize++;
        }
        else {
            entry->second.second->value = value;
            incrementFrequency(entry->second);
        }
    }

    bool get(K key, V &value) {
        auto entry = cacheMap.find(key);
        if (entry == cacheMap.end())
            return false;
        value = entry->second.second->value;
        incrementFrequency(entry->second);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Here are examples of usage:

```
    int main()
    {
        LFUCache<int>cache(3); // cache of size 3
        cache.set(1, 1);
        cache.set(2, 2);
        cache.set(3, 3);
        cache.set(2, 4); 

        rc = cache.get(1, r);

        assert(rc);
        assert(r == 1);
        // evict old element, in this case 3
        cache.set(4, 5);
        rc = cache.get(3, r);
        assert(!rc);
        rc = cache.get(4, r);
        assert(rc);
        assert(r == 5);

        LFUCache<int, string>cache2(2);
        cache2.set(1, "one");
        cache2.set(2, "two");
        string val;
        rc = cache2.get(1, val);
       if (rc)
          assert(val == "one");
       else
          assert(false);

       cache2.set(3, "three"); // evict 2
       rc = cache2.get(2, val);
       assert(rc == false);
       rc = cache2.get(3, val);
       assert(rc);
       assert(val == "three");

}
```

Comment: I've thought about this... why not have a 2d doubly linked list where each element of the first dimension is a frequency and the second the elements that the hash map of the cache points into that have pointers to the root? When a get is performed, just pull put of one doubly linked list, follow the pointer to the root, move up one and add to the next frequency list (or extend array if necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of LFU cache in Go/Golang based on [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-kahadb-store/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/util/LFUCache.java).

```
import "container/list" 

type LFU struct {
    cache      map[int]*list.Element
    freqQueue  map[int]*list.List
    cap        int
    maxFreq    int
    lowestFreq int
}

type entry struct {
    key, val int
    freq     int
}

func NewLFU(capacity int) *LFU {
    return &LFU{
        cache:      make(map[int]*list.Element),
        freqQueue:  make(map[int]*list.List),
        cap:        capacity,
        maxFreq:    capacity - 1,
        lowestFreq: 0,
    }
}

// O(1)
func (c *LFU) Get(key int) int {
    if e, ok := c.cache[key]; ok {
        val := e.Value.(*entry).val
        c.updateEntry(e, val)
        return val
    }

    return -1
}

// O(1)
func (c *LFU) Put(key int, value int) {
    if e, ok := c.cache[key]; ok {
        c.updateEntry(e, value)

    } else {
        if len(c.cache) == c.cap {
            c.evict()
        }

        if c.freqQueue[0] == nil {
            c.freqQueue[0] = list.New()
        }
        e := c.freqQueue[0].PushFront(&entry{key, value, 0})
        c.cache[key] = e
        c.lowestFreq = 0
    }
}

func (c *LFU) updateEntry(e *list.Element, val int) {
    key := e.Value.(*entry).key
    curFreq := e.Value.(*entry).freq

    c.freqQueue[curFreq].Remove(e)
    delete(c.cache, key)

    nextFreq := curFreq + 1
    if nextFreq > c.maxFreq {
        nextFreq = c.maxFreq
    }

    if c.lowestFreq == curFreq && c.freqQueue[curFreq].Len() == 0 {
        c.lowestFreq = nextFreq
    }

    if c.freqQueue[nextFreq] == nil {
        c.freqQueue[nextFreq] = list.New()
    }
    newE := c.freqQueue[nextFreq].PushFront(&entry{key, val, nextFreq})
    c.cache[key] = newE
}

func (c *LFU) evict() {
    back := c.freqQueue[c.lowestFreq].Back()
    delete(c.cache, back.Value.(*entry).key)
    c.freqQueue[c.lowestFreq].Remove(back)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).