# Speed a search cache without using too much memory

Tags: java, caching, arraylist, hashmap

I have to access a database with 380,000 entries. I don't have write access to the DB, I can just read it. I've made a search function using  a map to search for users by firstname. Here is my process:
1 - Load everything from the DB
2 - Store everything into a `Map<Charactere, ArrayList<User>>`, using Alpha letters to store users according to the first letter of their firstname.

```
<A> {Alba, jessica, Alliah jane, etc ...}
<B> {Birsmben bani, etc ...}
```

When someone searches for a user, I take the firstletter of the firstname typed and use `map.get(firstletter)`, then iterate on the ArrayList to find all the users.

The Map Take a huge space in the memory I guess (380,000 User object). I had to increase the heap size
I want to make it faster. Use firstname as key for the Map, in order to make it faster (there are many people with the same firstname).

I have two solutions in mind:

```
1 - Still use a map with firstname as key (increasing the heap size again?)
2 - Use files on the disk instead of Map (Alba.dat will contain all Alba for example) and open the right file for each search. No need to incease the heap size, but are there any side effects?
```

Which one is better? (pros and cons)

```
Update with more info
```

It's a database of customers who calls our customer service on the phone. The person who takes the call has to search using the customers names (usually firstname and then lastname). Using the Db is too slow to search. The solution I've implemented is much faster already (1/2 seconds vs 26 seconds using the db), but I want to improve it.

Comment: Are you assuming that data once loaded will never change in database by someone else? Why do you need to cache the full data and not the most used data? Please explain the problem domain, its hard to see why you would need to maintain the copy of entire database in memory. If so, have you considered using a in memory database?

Comment: I refresh the cache every 5 minutes. It's a base of customers and I have no idea which names are most frequently searched. I don't have to maintain a whole copy of the DB, just a copy of the users (firstname, lastname, id, list of documents)

Comment: Is there any last modified column in that database? Getting the 380K records every 5 mins is going to be very expensive.

Comment: How do you need to search for data? In other words, whats the key and what are you searching for? i.e. will you be searching the records on first name, last name, first name + last name? Is id the unique key? If you get 2 users with same first and last name , then what will you return back?

Comment: I search by using firstname or firstname, lastname. For example, a search query for "Jessica Alba" can be "Alba, j*" or "Alb*, jess*".  I search for a specific user and all documents related to this customer. The customers are differenciated by their id. It doesn't matter if they have same firstname/lastname. I don't have the right to modify the DB. and it takes 2 seconds to refresh the cache.

Comment: Best solution for you will be an in memory database like H2. However, I dont have any figures to confirm how fast it will be. The idea is to convert your data into a simple column based table, which can be inserted/ refreshed every 5 minutes in your in memory database and query from there. I think the searches may get faster as you should be able to index. Since its running in memory in same machine and possibly same jvm, retrieves should be faster. But you need to do a POC to be sure.

Comment: You could use a [PrefixTrie](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html) that is refreshed with the user's id as the value. Then lookup into a bounded user cache, which will keep the most frequently requested users. That should reduce memory with similar performance. Later move to a search engine like Elastic when you need a more robust, general search solution.

Comment: Super! Thanks Rishi Goel and Ben Manes. I'll go for the apache PrefixTrie for now and then use H2 later.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, I don't think you have to cache all the entries in memory, but a part of them, maybe:

- Maybe just use a ring buffer, or
- More complicated, and make more sense, to implement a LFU Cache, that keeps the N top most frequently accessed item only. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117636/how-to-implement-a-least-frequently-used-lfu-cache) for a hint of how to implement such a cache.

Comment: The problem is I don't know which are the most frequently used names. They didn't record that type of activities.

Comment: Base on run-time activities (the 'get' action), LFU algorithm will help you to keep most frequently used items and evict those less used. You don't need to identify it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your approach:

- It implies that the number in users doesn't change, a good application design would work with any number of users without software change
- It implies that the current problem is the only one. What happens if the next requirement that needs implementation is "search by caller id" or "search by zip code"?
- It is reinventing the wheel, you are currently starting to write a database, index or information retrieval solution (however you want to name it) from scratch

The right thing to do is to export the user data into a database engine which provides proper search capabilities. The export/extraction hopefully can be speed up, if you have modification time stamps or if you can intercept updates and reapply it to your search index.

What you use for your search does not matter to much, a simple database on a modern system is fast enough. Most also provide indexing capabilities to speed up your search. If you want something which can be embedded in your application and is specialized on search and solves your problems above, I'd recommend using Lucene.

Comment: - Even if the number users changes it's ok, because the cache is being refreshed every 5 minutes (it takes about 4 secs to refresh, with a mirror system the the Map is never empty) / For other kind of searches I use already use the DB (by phone number oy by zip code). The problem is it's slow when search by names. For the rest I don't want to reinvent the wheel, just write something simple to speed up the search. It works fine already. I just want t imporve